# Magento: text field type attribute in layered navigation

Tags: magento, attributes

I have an attribute called "total" defined as text Field which I want to use in layered navigation but I am not able to use because magento wont allow text field attribute in layered navigation.

Is there any way to get text field attribute type filtration in layered navigation?

Comment: MageAKash,According to magento functionality you cannot  show text type attribute in layer naviation.Only dropdown and multi select attribute is showed.

Comment: thanks amit i know magento not provide this kind of functionality but is there any way we can get this work?

Comment: check this this is the whatz you needed
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/attribute-in-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference link from where i added price filter in navigation pannel, try it if works for you.

`http://magebug.blogspot.in/2013/11/magento-add-custom-price-box-in-layered.html`

Comment: thanks S.Pandav, magento provides price attribute as filterable in layered navigation but its not providing text field filterable in layered navigation.